# Creating a python function that uses sockets to get HTML from a passed URL

Tags: python, sockets

I'd like to create a method that returns the HTML for a url that's passed as a parameter.  I'm aware of how to do this using tools like "urllib2" or "requests".  However, I am restricted to using sockets.  So far i've tried this and it's not working.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((url, 80))
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
return s.recv(4096)
```

The error is with the request, I think it's formatted incorrectly.

I've tried some similar solutions from other users here, but none of them have worked.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It depends on the url passed.  For example, when I pass "www.stackoverflow.com" I get... HTTP/1.1 500 Domain Not Found

<title>Fastly error: unknown domain </title>
...
<p>Fastly error: unknown domain: . Please check that this domain has been added to a service.</p>
...

Comment: The errors are all of that style, with differing semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the `Host` header is mandatory only with HTTP/1.1 it is actually needed by many sites even if you are doing a HTTP/1.0 request, especially if they host different domains on the same IP address. So what you need is at least the following:

```
  s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " + hostname + "\r\n\r\n")
```

Note that some sites also require specific `User-Agent` values or other headers since they are trying to detect and block bots. And, sites often reply with a HTTP redirect, so if you want to get to the HTML you need to be able to parse the response, follow the redirect (and also include a given cookie in the new request), probably also deal with HTTPS instead of plain HTTP etc.

Comment: Does the socket object have a way of getting the hostname?

Comment: @Xlqt: A socket is associated with a local IP address and the IP address it is connected to. It has no idea of hostnames, only of IP addresses. The `hostname` I have in the code is actually what you falsely claimed to be the `url`. A URL is something like `http://hostname:port/path...` but you only need the hostname or IP address in the socket and only give this (and the port) when connecting the socket and not the full URL.